# Create variable by html button and use it in outside function

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

Is there any way to make it work?

I´ve read that "let can be only available inside the scope it's declared, like in for loop, on the other hand "var" can be accessed outside the loop for example"

HTML:

```js
let create = document.getElementById("create");
let add = document.getElementById("add");
let cart = document.getElementById("cart");

create.onclick = function(){
  var foo = "foo";
  console.log(foo);
}

add.onclick = function(){
  cart.innerHTML += foo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="create">create</button>
    <button id="add">Add to cart</button>
    <h2 id="cart">Cart: </h2>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: If that's a direct quote from something, that something is horribly phrased. `var` variables are scoped to their containing function, `const` and `let`s are scoped to their containing block

Comment: You can declare `foo` outside, but then what'd you want to happen if `add` is clicked before `show` is clicked? (maybe only allow a click on `add` after `show` is clicked?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the click event for `add` inside the `show` click event handler function by passing the the variable:

```js
let show = document.getElementById("show");
let add = document.getElementById("add");
let cart = document.getElementById("cart");

show.onclick = function(){
  var foo = "foo";
  console.log(foo);
  add.addEventListener('click', function() { addToCart(foo); });
}

function addToCart(f){
  cart.innerHTML += f;
}
```

```html
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="add">Add to cart</button>
<h2 id="cart">Cart: </h2>
```